# No video signal from PC after car ride

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, troubleshooting

So I've just moved across country and now my PC is no longer working. I've set up everything as usual and noticed that I'm getting no video signal. What I've tried so far (in order):

1. Veryfing that the monitor works by testing it with my laptop.
2. Removing the GPU and connecting the monitor directly to the motherboard.
3. Disconnecting the hard drives.
4. Trying all RAM-slots with only one of my two bars.
5. Removing the RAM.

All fans and LEDs were turning everytime, the laser on the mouse is working and the lights for numpad and capslock are turning on/off as i hit the buttons. When I'm turning the PC on with no RAM, the PC turns off and on again after a few seconds. Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: I'm currently editing my specs into the post

My specs:

Motherboard: ASRock B450M Steel Legend
GPU: Zotac GTX 1080
CPU: Ryzen 5 2600x
RAM: 2x 8GB G.SKILL TridentZ RGB F4-3200C16D-16GTZR

Comment: If there is no hard drive present, does it start in BIOS?  I do not think so according to the above but please verify. So then, reseat any cards, memory, CPU (with thermal paste) and GPU (with thermal paste). That is, reseat everything and then test again without the hard drive and see if it starts in BIOS

Comment: Hi, it does not start into BIOS, the screen stays completely black

Comment: A repair-shop is indicated.

Comment: Hey everyone, I fixed it. I breadboarded the PC, and during a search i found out that my CPU does not have integrated graphics, so connecting the motherboard directly to the mainboard could not yield to a picture. I put the GPU back in and magically got a picture! I assume the GPU loosened itself.